# How can I connect to the database?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android native application in Eclipse using Java and I added that MySQL connector for Java. I want to display data from database in mobile emulator. I'm unable to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you're connecting to the database, but the [docs about networking in the Android emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) may be of some help. In particular, if the database is running on the machine that is also running the emulator then configure the app to connect to the IP address 10.0.2.2

Comment: Hi Jon, I am using eclipse IDE, Android SDK 2.2, JDK 6.0.2, mysql 6.54 and mySQL-Connector-java-5.1.7.bin.jar. When I am trying to connect to DB then I am getting error "com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationException: Communications link failure". Can you please guide me in this context. Thanks for your help. I would appreciate if you can tell me the steps to connect. I am a new bie on android and java platform. Thnx

Comment: Can you post the line of your code where you connect to the database (probably something like DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", username, password);)

Comment: Connection conn = null;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String dbName = "vdemo";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "root"; 
      String password = "root";Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);String url = ""; url = "jdbc:mysql://" + "localhost:3306" + "/" + "vdemo"; Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello, readers of MobiForge! - " + txtbox1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); connect("localhost", 3306, "vdemo", "root", "root");

Comment: Assuming that the database is running on the machine that you're running the emulator on then you probably just need to change every time it says localhost to say 10.0.2.2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTTPClient`

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html